# What's the purpose of the "stackoverflow" user on Transifex and how does it relate to the "traducir.win" user?

Tags: bug, localization, transifex, traducir

I caught a weird [translation issue on ruSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11585/176217) and found an interesting moment on Transifex.

> [image: Transifex ping-pong]

For some reason, the "stackoverflow" user adds an unnecessary space symbol right before (according the [translation history page](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/320139899?q=key%3A4ecdf83027737dbe3ded9ce04bdb3282)) the update by the "traducir.win" user.

"traducir.win" is used as a proxy user to publish a translation on Transifex via the [Traducir.win](https://ru.traducir.win) site.

Despite the correct last translation on Transifex (by the traducir.win user) ruSO still uses an incorrect translation (by the "stackoverflow" user) with an extra space inside the hyperlink syntax. What is happening here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `stackoverflow` user is what we (Stack Overflow) use to push new strings to transifex. Another thing we use it for is to manage "overrides".

These overrides are set by us. Sometimes, these overrides were put in there because the person working on the feature wasn't aware of Traducir. But it can also be used so that the community can't provide a translation for a string.

Right now, the `stackoverflow` and `traducir.win` are racing to have their version win (but... `stackoverflow` always wins, despite Traducir's TLD)

This string in particular, in English is:

> By clicking “Accept all cookies”, you agree Stack Exchange can store cookies on your device and disclose information in accordance with our Cookie Policy.

I've confirmed internally that we want to manage the cookie / legal stuff ourselves, so those strings need to be translated by us (and traducir's values won't affect what's shown on the site).

:facepalm: and I just realized the problem is the space... I tweaked that on the database so that `stackoverflow` doesn't break the link each time.

Comment: Good to have a familiar face back in action. Welcome back and enjoy!

Comment: thanks! happy to be back :) also happy for my face to be familiar around here